# Should I tell my boss I have discovered their passwords and they are too weak?

Tags: passwords, privacy

I'm on a temporary job so they don't give me any passwords to access the sites and resources I need. Instead, they tell me to move to another computer where a regular employee is and where every password is already set and saved on the browser.

I have to be honest, I got into the router (as they are using default credentials) to get the WiFi password so I can use it on my phone and found that it had a lot to do with the activity the company does (*e.g. if they were a restaurant, their password would be coffe123*). With that in mind, I just wanted to see if the same pattern was used for other types of resources such as the email address, hosting accounts, etc. and yes, they were.

When registering another domain with a new account, I guessed the password by seeing my boss slowly typing on the keyboard and, again, weak as f*.

Should I tell them? I'm afraid I might get in trouble for lurking too much.

*Just as a clarification: it's not a big company, we are just a few employees and none of them but me know about computers and security, so there's no way of anonimously reporting the issue or contacting a sysadmin or IT related guy.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53101/discussion-on-question-by-sysfiend-should-i-tell-my-boss-i-have-discovered-their).

Comment: You should google "randal schwartz felony conviction", and take all the warnings that people have given you here very seriously.  His situation was very similar to yours.

Comment: I'm thinking this question would be more on-topic in workplace.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 164, accepted):

While there is no doubt that weak passwords are an issue for your company, I would strongly advise against telling your boss about the things that you have done.

Your company decided against giving temporary workers access to sites and resources for a reason. Not only did you gain unauthorized access to the wireless LAN by guessing the password to the router, you also extended that access by probing the credentials against other resources - Resources that you were not supposed to have the password to. You then basically shoulder surfed your boss.

While there seem to be flaws in your employers policy concerning the access to company resources, and their password policies, all of these things could be considered 'hacking' by your employer and were definitely outside of your authorization.

If I were you I would log off the WLAN and ask your employer for the password if you want to have access to it. Apart from that you should stop trying to use other peoples passwords on any access points just 'to see if the same pattern was used'. Depending on the legal system of the involved countries you can very well face legal problems for these kinds of acts.

**So what should you do with the information you have?**
If your employer gives you a password to a service or a resource you could point out, that e.g. that password would easily be guessable for other people. I would not mention the other password here directly though.
If your boss seems interested you could volunteer to research password best practices for the company. If they are serious about it, this would eliminate your concerns.
If there is an IT person in the company you could bring these concerns to him as he will probably understand the need for a secure password policy better.

Comment: curiosity killed the cat, they say... I just wanted to investigate a bit, no harm meant to be done.

Comment: I can definitely see the point from where you are coming and think that many people will feel the same curiosity. I also believe that you didn't want to do any harm. Others that look at this with another mindset however, will often feel different, which unfortunately has caused a lot of people a lot of problems in the past.

Comment: I do also feel bad having this knowledge and don't telling them anything so they could be hacked by a bad guy any time..

Comment: Try feeling bad about obtaining that knowledge instead. (sorry, that doesn't make you feel any better) If I had a good relationship with the employer, I'd confess and share the knowledge, but in your case, it sounds like that approach would backfire.

Comment: Curiosity doesn't only kill the cat it can get you fired yesterday as well :)

Comment: @HankyPanky Not just fired, but at least in the U.S., can get you sent to prison as well.

Comment: @sysfiend You say no harm done, but I know someone who was almost fired for discovering a bug in an internal website. Wasn't doing anything malicious, he was using the website and found it and another group tried to get him fired for "hacking" their website.

Comment: @sysfiend You should read up on the [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act) respectively inform yourself of your country's laws regarding the issue at hand. tldr: If you're in the US you probably technically committed a **felony** depending on the circumstances. Getting terminated for cause would be the least of your worries at that point. Not going to happen in this case, but you have to understand that accessing computer systems without authorization is a very serious offense.

Comment: `Not only did you gain unauthorized access to the wireless LAN by guessing the password to the router...` Or more likely, trying probable passwords until one worked. Not the kind of thing one should admit to, though any invalid attempts may still be logged somewhere.

Comment: What did the cat want to know?

Comment: @Denis I believe your answer would (and should) be strengthened by a reference to the Randal Schwartz felony conviction for activities strikingly similar to OPs.  OP has probably figured this out from all the comments here, but future readers are probably going to read your answer and it would be good to warn them of the real danger they face even if they volunteer the information and meant no harm.

Comment: @voo I recall there are some people who explicitly have bots basically hack websites using simple or common methods, and when they succeed, offer to tell the website owner about the hack/vulnerability for money. Its a very similar situation, so if they were in the US, are they committing a Felony by doing so, or at what point are/would they be?

Answer (score 41):

Unless you have received an explicit or implicit(*) mandate for doing so, trying to guess passwords to access resources that were not granted to you **is** a hostile action, even if the passwords are trivial or written in a place that you should not have read. If you find a leaflet with "Confidential - reserved for allowed people" on cover page and you read it nonetheless, it is also a hostile action.

The most you can do is in the case of the leaflet say "I've seen there a confidential document there, that someone could read without anybody else noticing it. Does it really contain sensitive information and if so shouldn't it be stored in a more secure place?" -> meaning I have seen a possible security problem and I warned you but **I** have respected the *confidential* mark.

Or if you have discovered the password of a co-worker (and if the following story is possible): "Hey I had to log on a computer, I was thinking about something else, and I entered a password I use at home. Then I realized that I was logged on your account. I immediately logged out, but you really should change that password for a professional account"

---

*Mandate can be implicit if you are in charge of evaluating the overall security. But in that case you should ask whether you can continue as soon as you have discovered a trivial password.

Comment: The story of the last paragraph might apply if the simple password is something like 123456, but if it is [product-of-the-firm]123 it is no longer plausible that the OP uses that password at home.

Answer (score 30):

I'm saying much the same thing as others, but this really could be a legal concern for you (I'm not a lawyer). In the UK (*) one relevant act is the [Computer Misuse Act 1990](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/1) which says right at the start:

> 1 Unauthorised access to computer material.
>
> (1)A person is guilty of an offence if—
>
> (a)he causes a computer to perform any function with intent to secure
>   access to any program or data held in any computer
>
> (b)the access he intends to secure [F2, or to enable to be secured,]
>   is unauthorised; and
>
> (c)he knows at the time when he causes the computer to perform the
>   function that that is the case.

i.e. if you so much as *try* to access anything that you know you shouldn't.

Subsection 2 says it doesn't matter what computer, what data, or what kind of data, nothing makes it OK.

Subsection 3 says:

> (3)A person guilty of an offence under this section shall be liable—
>
> (a)on summary conviction in England and Wales, to imprisonment for a
>   term not exceeding 12 months or to a fine not exceeding the statutory
>   maximum or to both;

And then section 2 of the act says *Unauthorised access with intent to commit or facilitate commission of further offences.* - you committed an act of unauthorized access (gaining router access) so that you could commit another act of unauthorized access (wifi access).

In one of your comments, you say

> no harm meant to be done

But Section 3 of the act is *Unauthorised acts with intent to impair, or with recklessness as to impairing, operation of computer, etc* - even if you don't *intend* harm, if you act recklessly, that's enough. Joining an unsecured, unknown, unauthorized, personal device (phone) to the company network 'could' put them at risk of all kinds of cryptolocker style blah blah.

I can strongly doubt that this will apply in force to someone in a small business accessing a router, but if they want to argue it, you've taken a temporary job, broken into their network, their email, their domain / website hosting, carelessly put their network and therefore their company operation at risk, and who knows what theft, blackmail, extortion or damage you were planning to commit.

And what's worse, they don't understand IT, they aren't interested in how much fun it is or how curious it is, or how serious or trivial your actions were, if they get the wrong end of the stick it won't look good for you.

> Should I tell my boss their passwords are too bad?

Yes, you *should*. But don't unless you have reason to think they will take it well. And they *should* care. But they don't. And it's not your company and not your problem. If they show interest, suggest why (in principle) stored browser passwords are risky, or shared accounts are risky, or simple passwords are risky.

If there is no backup, encourage them to have backups. *"Hi, I was reading [this news item about GitLab almost losing 300Gb of data](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/01/gitlab_data_loss/) and it made me think we don't have good backups here - we could set one up for $xyz, what do you reckon?"*

(*) Other jurisdictions are available.

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2005/10/06/tsunami_hacker_convicted/ - actual case where someone was prosecuted and found guilty for doing far less than the question describes here...

Comment: Laws are similar in the US, though they vary by state.

Comment: @Chris Unauthorized access of computers in the US can very easily be a felony, so laws in the US are generally even more serious than the UK version the way I read it (for an extreme example see Aaron Swartz's case where violation of the same law the OP is guilty resulted in multiple felony counts and a maximum criminal exposure of up to 50 years in prison).

Comment: I scanned this answer pretty quickly and missed the part about a max of a 12 months sentence. By "Laws are similar" I wasn't inferring anything about severity of punishment.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider I didn't quote everything, offenses under different sections of the act I linked have different punishments. Offenses causing or risking 'serious damage to human welfare or national security' can go up to 'imprisonment for life'.

Comment: On the no harm meant to be done bit:  Legal systems generally do not care about the notion of lack of malicious intent, only that a statute has been broken.

Comment: It’s ironic that using legal threats to cover up poor security just makes the security *worse* against actual hostile actors.

Comment: With passwords saved in the browser, I wonder if clicking the readily available "show passwords" button in the browser settings counts as computer misuse ...

Comment: Yeah, the Computer Fraud and Abuse Act could *easily* be invoked here. There are plenty of times in the US that our "hacking" laws have been applied in even [stupider circumstances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Swartz#JSTOR).

Answer (score 22):

I put myself in pretty much your exact situation once when I was young.  I got bored at a temp job and started probing around for security weaknesses.  I tried to end it by sending an anonymous email to the sysadmin, which backfired in the following ways:

- They freaked out, thinking the threat came from outside the company at first.
- They combed through the system logs and interrogated and nearly fired one of my coworkers who I was friends with and had nothing to do with anything.
- They eventually tracked it back to me and fired me.
- I was *very* lucky they didn't do worse.

The part about my friend nearly getting fired threw me for a loop.  In my hubris, I was *completely* unaware of any collateral damage I might be causing.  Also what surprised me was when I got called into that room to be fired, how *scared* people were of me.  Dismiss any thoughts you have of people responding rationally.

My suggestion is *immediately stop* using any unauthorized access.  If you really can't do your job without a password, point that out, and if they give you that password, point out how weak it is.  Other than that, *leave it alone.*  I know it's difficult.  One day you'll be in a better position to influence these sorts of policies.  You just have to be patient.

Comment: Still not sure on the whole needing wifi access on his cell.  He's doing security, yet decides to get into the router without permission, so he can get the wifi password to connect his cell (aka an unsecured device) to the company network, and most likely without permission?

Comment: maybe you should've been honest earlier ?! amused by the scared part, though !

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your username in relation to what you've described? Also, +1, good answer. Nice and honest of you to share.

Comment: Didn't you come out when they started investigating?  Might have avoided the firing.

Answer (score 15):

Don't start by talking about the insecure passwords. Instead start by pointing out that it's not a secure practice for you to use another employee's computer to access systems because it puts the other user's data at risk (of an accident even if you aren't malicious or as nosy as you are). Try to convince them that it would be more secure to give you the passwords that you need to do your job. It would also be more efficient since you wouldn't have to block the other user from working. If they want you to have access they should give you that access. If that works, then you can comment on the insecure passwords that they reveal to you. If they are concerned about you knowing the passwords after you leave they can change them at that time.

Answer (score 10):

Most companies of any size have a mechanism by which you can make anonymous reports of wrongdoing by members of staff. It may be called an integrity of a compliance reporting system.

This sort of whistleblowing is encouraged to protect the company from more damaging revelations.

I would check if your employer has such a system and, if so, use it.  Report the names of people involved and, if you feel it appropriate, even the password they are using.

Where I work, such reports are encouraged.  You would be helping the company secure its data without risk to yourself.

Comment: It's a really small company and I'm the only one with computer knowledge. Even if such policy existed, I'd be exposed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend reporting the actual passwords used. If they're the default passwords it will be obvious. If further investigations are needed, you don't want to have people "testing" the passwords of management accounts.

Comment: And a large company can check logs and figure out if anyone recently was on that part of the network without authorization.  Really bad idea to be anonymous after doing a crime.  Hey cops someone is driving drunk on highway 64 right now.... wait its me.

Comment: @blankip  Any small company worth a darned would check it's logs as well lol.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I tell my boss their passwords are too bad?

When I am working on a project, and I am given the password to a server/router etc, and it's a bad password I will always say something, and recommend using stronger passwords/a password manager etc.

I think that this is a reasonable thing to do.

> With that in mind, I just wanted to see if the same pattern was used for other types of resources such as the email address, hosting accounts, etc. and yes, they were.

Yeah, definitely don't do this. It is against the law, and you could end up with a criminal record if your employer found out.

Answer (score 4):

By telling them you would end up revealing the actions you've taken to gain that information and that might get you in trouble.

If you want to educate them about the importance of strong passwords, you might be able to do so without divulging what you know.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with the others that you have gone too far in probing the security, and that you should not tell your employer about the passwords/systems you have compromised, I think you have a responsibility to tell them that their security practices appear to be poor and ask for their permission to investigate further.

(but make sure you have a go-ahead in writing, off-site before you go any further)

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, it all depends on your boss' personality and how much you know/trust each other. There's many employers that couldn't care less about their employees and would take advantage of such situation by suing you, but at the same time there's many that would be very grateful for such advice, and befriend you for doing extra work.

You could say something along the lines of "I was watching tutorials on network security and I was wondering whether the system here had such flaws" or if not, you could find a trustworthy employee to say that, which would probably be more accepted by your boss.

And finally, there's always the dont-say-anything approach and just do your job, mind your own business, and forget about it. Seems wrong, but nowadays there's too many bad people that want to take advantage of genuinely good deeds (like pointing out flaws in a business' security) that it's not really worth the risk of going to jail and paying  fines for trying to be a nice person.

The only one that can make a move is you, and that all depends on how good your judgement of people's personalities is.

Answer (score 2):

> And finally, there's always the dont-say-anything approach and just do
>   your job, mind your own business, and forget about it. Seems wrong,
>   but nowadays there's too many bad people that want to take advantage
>   of genuinely good deeds (like pointing out flaws in a business'
>   security) that it's not really worth the risk of going to jail and
>   paying fines for trying to be a nice person.

And that's exactly what you should do. If you say a word, even a hint, to anybody--anybody!, not just the boss, or others at that company--you are putting your safety and liberty in his hands. Keep your mouth shut, do your job, and go somewhere else to work after your contract is done. Your situation is *dangerous*. Prosecutors are rewarded for number of convictions, not the evil of the perpetrator.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote this, it's exactly correct.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the personality of your boss. Is he intelligent, smart and understanding? If yes then you can tell him. That will not be the cause to fire you or demote you by any chance. Instead, you might be rewarded for your talent and who knows, may be a promotion too.

But if the personality of your Boss is rather ordinary, then just forget this.

Answer (score 1):

Try asking them for the password, because of blah blah blah. If they know that you know the password, you can tell them it's insecure and they'll, most likely, agree to changing it! And since you got the password in a "good" way, you will be FINE.

Answer (score -1):

Note: take everything said there with a grain of salt, I'm trying to provide a point to why you might not need a high security, but that does not mean you should not have any security.

---

I might play the devil's advocate here, but security is risk vs reward.

So him having a weak password might not entail much, worst case scenario being a few of hours of slowdown if someone gets access to the IT system.

But him forgetting his password "h1Ed4H£2h~zE{G~b#1$ù%µ454" and/or wasting 5-10 minutes per day by entering it and him being frustrated because he gets it wrong a few times would probably be worse in the long term.

What I mean is that sometimes we get caught in a security paranoia and forget that the risk of someone willing to attack the company is not really high, and even a full IT failure may only mean having to go back to paper for a few days.

---

As for how to deal with it, I suggest casually talking with your boss about IT security, and if he thinks it's important or not. You may argue if your points hold.

If your boss agrees that IT security is important, you might want to ask him if you can probe around to see if there are any problems with the security. Do what you did, conscientiously and report on him via a mail with every problem you find, what risk that means, and how/how much to fix it.

Most of the time the problems with IT security come not from external sources, but from (ex-)employees with a grudge, so that's probably why he doesn't want you to get the passwords.

Comment: `What I mean is that sometimes we get caught in a security paranoia and forget that the risk of someone willing to attack the company is not really high`. A healthy amount of paranoia is necessary. If it was trivial for OP to guess this password, it'll be trivial for an attacker.

Comment: "*Most of the time the problems with IT security come not from external sources, but from (ex-)employees with a grudge*" is the only thing I agree with you. How can you say "*even a full IT failure may **only** mean having to go back to paper for a few days*"?. Lmao

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ But "does an attacker exist" is the first question. And the second one is "what would be the worst the attacker can do". I'm not saying it's wrong to worry about security, though I may have emphasized a bit too much my point. but most small businesses don't need to worry that much about IT security. Of course if your risks are more than just an unlikely slow down due to someone on the inside, you might worry about it. 
That is why I suggest brainstorming with the boss about what is really needed as far as IT security goes. Getting better passwords should be an easy conclusion.

Comment: @sysfired well, where I work, we rely a lot on IT, but we have a plan B for everything, and can make everything work on paper and humans. 
I'm not sure what your company does, so I can't say that it is doable for yours, but if you do something like a restaurant (to take your example), you can still take clients at the register on a note, even if your registration system and your website are down. If you are company that works only on websites, that is probably not doable though.

Comment: @satibel there might never be an attacker but, what if so? Also, if he breaks into the security of a business that has no passwords policy of any kind, he would have access to bank, paypal and hosting accounts, at least. It's not about having the work done, it's about protecting the company's money and data

Comment: @sysfired Then if an attacker can gain access to these accounts, that IS a security concern, a reason for someone to want to break in in the first place, and should be an argument for having better security.

Even if you are attacked, and those accounts are taken, you probably can get access back to those accounts, change the passwords, and get your money back in less than a month (probably even a week, given it's a business.).